# How to set up a nightly job that runs a script on Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, automation, azure-sql

I'm looking for a way to set up a nightly job that will run a small SQL Script, to rebuild fragmented indexes on an Azure SQL database. Resources I have found online seem to be either dated, or involve setting up the job on a local machine.

Comment: Are you looking for Azure Automation? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-en/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two easy options:

**Web Jobs**

You can run programs or scripts in WebJobs in Azure App Service web app. Any script written in The following file types are accepted:

- .cmd, .bat, .exe (using windows cmd)
- .ps1 (using powershell)
- .sh (using bash)
- .php (using php)
- .py (using python)
- .js (using node)
- .jar (using java)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs

**Azure Automation**

Basically allows you to run anything that can be executed with PowerShell cmdlets on a schedule, continuous or on-demand way.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro

Azure Automation comes with 500min. free. If you need assistance setting up the basics here's a good setup guide.

**Getting Started Querying your Azure SQL Database in PowerShell**

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4224/getting-started-querying-your-azure-sql-database-in-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

To perform *scheduled tasks on Azure*, in addition to **Web Jobs** and **Automation Accounts** as *Bruno* mentioned, you can also use **Azure Functions**:

> **Azure Functions** is a solution for easily running small pieces of code, or "functions," in the cloud.
> You can use your development language of choice, such as **C#**, **F#**, **Node.js**, **Python** or **PHP**.
>
> ...
>
> Azure Functions supports *triggers*, which are ways to start execution of your code.
>
> **TimerTrigger** - executes cleanup or other batch tasks on a predefined schedule.

[MSDN: Introduction to Azure Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview)

Here is a good **example** how to create a scheduled SQL task with **Azure Functions** on MSDN:
[Use Azure Functions to perform a scheduled clean-up task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup)